# Javascript: get first character from string error

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to get first character from strings like this

```
//'M 25.508,12.011' or 'L25.508,12.011'
```

using both methods

```
str.substring(0,1); or str.charAt(0)
```

In both cases I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of string 'M 25.508,12.011'
```

Please, what can I do?

Comment: Try to share a fiddle..You may not experience this issue by the time you create a fiddle..

Comment: are you trying to assign that substring to a property?  That seems like where the error is and not the substring itself

Comment: I added fiddle, please check.

Comment: We don't need a jsFiddle. We need an actual example of the code that is causing the error to be included directly in the question. Your demo doesn't give any such error. It does however give an error because you're calling `.charAt()` on an Array.

Comment: path(path1) returns Array of Array and you get the first char from path(path1)[0][0] - use console.log(np); to check that in path function

Comment: @TeroTolonen true, I typed wrong some stuff indeed. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript a string is simply and object of characters or an array of characters.  This array is zero based.  You can simply use the folowing

```
alert("hello"[0]);   // this will return "h"
```

In your example

```
alert (str[0]);
```

Also Note:  Your error

> ...assign to read only property '0'...

You cannot assign to a character of a string.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with str.substr(0,1); and it works

Answer (score -1):

try this really simple fiddle it works actually

https://jsfiddle.net/deepakciitk2/gm285mux/

```
var str = "M 25.508,12.011"
alert(str.charAt(0))
```